# attempting to mimic the disconnect/reconnect of USB from inside my application

Tags: android, usb

I am working on a project where I need to put a USB device in to a reprogramming state and then send a software update to the device.  I have been able to make this work by having the user disconnect and reconnect the USB cable between the android device and the USB device I am reprogramming.  I have attempted many combinations of releasing interface and then trying to loop through the USBManager getDeviceList and then requestPermission on that device again.  I have tried modifying the PendingIntent to be different than the original PendingIntent.  I thought I had it once but it seems to have been a faulty OTG cable.  In a last ditch effort I tried to craft my own android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACH/DETACH message (which I got a Permission Denial on)  Any other ideas out there or is it just not possible?

Comment: Has anyone tried this.  I have never seen any responses to this

Comment: now I am just adding comments to my own post to try to get my reputation to a point where I can make a comment on another persons post... sorry